# notepad++ multi-instance settings - what is "open session in a new instance of notepad++"?

Tags: notepad++

What is the difference between "open session in a new instance of notepad++" and "always in multi-instance mode"?

I'm not seeing behavior differences.

Comment: [Official help page for multi-instance settings](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Multiple_Instances) does not make this more clear, maybe there are some hints, though.

Comment: @miroxlav you're right the help pages aren't very helpful on this point.  Some "hints" I took is the word "sessions" and digging in it seems something to do with remembering the views and folding and is stored in an XML file.  So I --think-- the implication is that if you open a new session file that would be in a new instance but real-world behavior seems more intricate than that.  Really wish I could find a clear answer.  Hope you or OP will update if you figure it out.

Comment: Ok, so I had to restart NP++ to see difference (my fault - missed warning in settings box).  Now I see that if NP is running and I try to open a new window from e.g. Start menu that it focuses currently open NP window but if I go to File -> Load Session I get a new window.  Presumably each session would remember it's tabs for next time but not sure if/how that works yet.

Comment: @JoelAZ – perhaps you can add this as the answer and accept it so your important finding won't  end buried in comments.

Comment: @miroxlav thanks but I don't think my findings are sufficient to be a complete answer.  There are 3 options in NP++ (not just two) and while I've figured out parts of the behavior I still don't understand all.  I think I'd rather it stay open so maybe someone who really *knows* the differences can explain.